# static/non-static method reference

Tags: java, static

I started creating a Hangman game. I want to have a main class, and a method class. I want to get a secret word, but I get an error:

> non-static method `getWord()` cannot be referenced from a static context.

Maybe I get this error because no object has been created? What's wrong here and how do I fix this?

PS: maybe implementing it with enum could be better, but I want to start this way.

```
public class HangmanMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String secretWord; /* chosen secret word*/
        secretWord = HangmanUtil.getWord();
        System.out.println("");
    }

}

public class HangmanUtil {

    private String[] wordBank = {"pool","ice", "america", "hook", "book", "glass" , "hint", "giraffe"," elephant", "ocean","market"};

    String guess;
    private int bodyPartsLeft;

    String getWord(){
        int len = wordBank.length;
        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * (len + 1));
        return wordBank[rand];
    }

}
```

Comment: "Maybe I get this error because no object has been created ?" - That's exactly right. You need to instantiate the containing class before you can call one of its non-static methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered yourself :

> Maybe I get this error because no object has been created ?

Either create a new instance of `HangmanUtil` or make the `HangmanUtil.getWord()` method static.

**EDIT** : considering it's a utility class, I believe second option is better : make `HangmanUtil` a static class with static methods.

Comment: Thanks:). "private static String[] wordBank =...," and "static String getWord(){..." solve the problem (and also create a new instance).    "public static class HangmanUtil {" doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, a class cannot be marked as `static`, only its content. You whould also make the constructor `private` to fully make the class "static".

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a method via `ClassName.methodName()` unless the method is static.

If you want to call a non-static method, you need an instance. E.g.

```
HangmanUtil hu = new HangmanUtil();
secretWord = hu.getWord();
```

If you don't want to make an instance, then your method needs to be be marked `static`, and any other methods or fields it references must also be static.